# Solving $ \sin x + \sin 2 x + \sin 3 x + \sin 4 x = 0 $

Tags: trigonometry

$$ \sin x + \sin 2 x + \sin 3 x + \sin 4 x = 0 $$
$$ 2 \sin 2x \cos x + 2 \sin 3 x \cos x = 0 $$
$$ \cos x ( \sin x + \sin 3 x = 0 ) $$

- $ \cos x = 0 $:
  $$ x = 2 n \pi \pm \frac \pi 2 $$
  $$ x = ( 2 k + 1 ) \frac \pi 2 $$
- $ \sin x + \sin 3 x = 0 $:
  $$ 2 \sin \left( \frac { 5 x } 2 \right) \sin \left( \frac x 2 \right) = 0 $$
  $$ \sin \frac { 5 x } 2 = 0 \quad \text , \quad \sin \frac x 2 = 0 $$
  $$ \frac { 5 x } 2 = n \pi \quad \text , \quad \frac x 2 = p \pi $$
  $$ x = \frac { 2 n \pi } 5 \quad \text , \quad x = 2 p \pi $$

$ $
$$ \large { x = ( 2 k + 1 ) \frac \pi 2 , \frac { 2 n \pi } 5 } $$

---

I have found two sets of values which satisfy the equation above, but the answer includes a set that I could not find.
$$ 4 x = \pi ( 2 p + 1 ) $$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of adding pictures, write down using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/697421)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin(x)+\sin(2 x)+\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)=\\
2\sin\left(\frac {5x} {2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {3x} {2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac {5x} {2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {x} {2}\right)=\\
2\sin\left(\frac {5x} {2}\right)\Big(\cos\left(\frac {3x} {2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac {x} {2}\right)\Big)=\\
2\sin\left(\frac {5x} {2}\right)\Big(2\cos(x)\cos\left(\frac {x} {2}\right)\Big)=0$$
$$\sin\left(\frac {5x} {2}\right)\cos(x) \cos\left(\frac {x} {2}\right)=0 \iff \dots $$

Comment: Mohsen Shahriari, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your work is mostly correct, except that it should be

$$ \sin(2x)+\sin(3x)=2\sin\left(\frac{5x}{2}\right)\color{red}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right).$$

Then the third set of solutions are

$$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=0\quad\implies\quad x=(2n+1)\pi,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:
$$ \sin a + \sin ( a + d ) + \dots + \sin \big( a + ( n - 1 ) d \big) = \frac { \sin \frac { n d } 2 } { \sin \frac d 2 } \cdot \sin \frac { a + \big( a + ( n - 1 ) d \big) } 2 $$
(for $ \sin \frac d 2 \ne 0 $)

Applying,
$$ \sin x + \sin 2 x + \sin 3 x + \sin 4 x = 0 $$
$$ \implies \frac { \sin \frac { 4 x } 2 } { \sin \frac x 2 } \cdot \sin \frac { 5 x } 2 = 0 $$
$$ \implies ( \sin 2 x ) \left( \sin \frac { 5 x } 2 \right) = 0 \quad \text {(with } \sin \frac x 2 \ne 0 \text ) $$
$$ \therefore \text {either } \sin 2 x = 0 \qquad \text {or } \sin \frac { 5 x } 2 = 0 $$
$$ \implies \text {either } 2 x = n \pi \text , \quad n \in \mathbb Z \qquad \text {or } \frac { 5 x } 2 = m \pi \text , \quad m \in \mathbb Z $$
$$ \therefore \boxed { x = \frac { n \pi } 2 , \frac { 2 m \pi } 5 } \text , \quad n , m \in \mathbb Z $$
Also, $ \sin \frac x 2 \ne 0 $ gives
$$ \frac x 2 \ne 2 k \pi \text , \quad k \in \mathbb Z $$
$$ \implies \boxed { x \ne 4 k \pi } \text , \quad k \in \mathbb Z $$

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: There are two problems with your work. Firstly, $ \sin \frac x 2 \ne 0 $ gives $ x \ne k \pi $ not $ 2 k \pi $. Secondly, and more importantly, the formula works **if** $ \sin \frac x 2 \ne 0 $; so you must check what happens when $ \sin \frac x 2 = 0 $, not just rule out that case.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Transform the sum into product :
$$\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)=$$
$$=4\sin(x)\sin\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\left(4\cos^2(x)+2\cos(x)-1\right)=0$$

Comment: How did you transform that sum into this specific product ?

Comment: Apply the wellknown relationships such as $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ ; $\sin(3x)=...$